# Special characters in Yii framework menu

Tags: yii, special-characters, menuitem

I'm developing a CMS using Yii Framework. In developing the theme I have a problem. In the menus I have some special characters (The website is in Italian). the HTML markups for special characters doesn't work for menu items. And if I put the character itself it looks different. Here is my code:

```
<div class="horizontal-menu">
     <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
       'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'LE ATTIVIT&Agrave;', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'attivita')),
            array('label'=>'NEWS', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'news')),
        ),
    )); ?>
```

`LE ATTIVITÀ` is the one making the problem. How can I show special characters here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CMenu](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMenu/)'s labels are HTML-encoded by default, so you should use `array('label'=>'LE ATTIVITÀ', 'url'=>array('/site/page', 'view'=>'attivita')),`.

However if you must use HTML-encoded strings in your code, you can turn the encoding off by setting the `encodeLabel` to false, like this `$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
       'items'=>array(),
       'encodeLabel'=>false, 
        ),`